# High energy electron diffraction of molecules in the gas measures what?

Tags: diffraction, molecules

For diffraction of an ensemble of molecules under suitable conditions, one can often read, that what one measures is a ensemble/thermal average of inverse distances, between scattering centers (atoms) of the molecules. Using the distances $r$ between these scattering centres the resulting experimentally measured parameters can then be expressed as $<r^{-1}>^{-1}$ when $<>$ denotes the averaging.

I would be interested in a concise explanation/derivation or at least some reference where I can check that.

Comment: Could you share an exemple of such readings? So that we can ascertain what domain of application we are concerned with here…

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis: Sure, here for example J. Phys. Chem. A, Vol. 113, No. 34, 2009 on page 9513 eqaution (1).

Comment: I would suggest you edit the title of your question to narrow it to the particular field of diffraction at hand. Indeed, in crystallography, the problematic is quite different for example, and I am afraid such a title will draw many readers from crystallography!

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis: Thank you very much for your considerations. Are you completely sure about XRD? When you measure the metrics of the reciprocal lattice experimentally, you measure the distances between the reflections. So in essence you measure as well $1/r$, namely thermally averaged. And in a sense the cell measurement is really the most essential measurement of your XRD, no?

Comment: You are correct about the cell but then there is more to XRD than that. In chemical crystallography (single crystal and powder too these days), one probes the 3D structure of the molecules too and the model is different from what I explained in my answer. Related, in the case of powder, but not quite the same emphasis on the inverse intra-molecular distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is in the context of Gas Electron Diffraction. The energy of the electrons is chosen such that each molecule of the gas diffracts the electrons. Since the molecules are randomly oriented, the situation is similar to that of powder crystallography: one measures only one angle of diffraction $\theta$. Precisely, the experimental output is the intensity $I(s)$ for a range of $s=4\pi(\sin\theta/2)/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the electrons. This is then compared to a theoretical prediction [2] (my go-to reference for gas electron diffraction: it is old but as far as the theory goes, it is still relevant),

$$I(s)\propto \sum_{ij}f_i(s)f_j(s)\frac{\sin sr_{ij}}{sr_{ij}},$$

where the indices $i$ and $j$ label the atoms of a molecule: $r_{ij}$ is then the distance between atom $i$ and $j$ whereas $f_i(s)$ models the diffraction by atom $i$.

The curve of $I(s)$ will have peaks at the values of $s$ for which $\sin(sr_{ij})/sr_{ij}$ is maximum. It is a classic result that those are $r_{ij}^{-1}$ times the solutions of $\tan x = x$. Thus, it can be said that by locating one peak in the measured curve $I(s)$, one effectively measures one $r_{ij}^{-1}$. In practice, peaks may overlap for large-ish molecules and one resorts to least-squares fit of the model to the measured values to find the $r_{ij}$'s but since the data point near the maxima discussed above will dominate, we reach the same conclusion, blurred by the statistical machinery, but the same nevertheless: we effectively measure the inverse of the intra-molecular atomic distances.

Final point: the above model is too crude as it neglects intra-molecular vibrations: the electrons take a frozen snapshot of the $r_{ij}$'s for each molecule and they differ slightly from one molecule to the next. Thus we can only determine an average of the values of $1/r_{ij}^{-1}$, which is what the equation (1) in the paper you cited is about [1].

[1] Derek A. Wann, Alexander V. Zakharov, Anthony M. Reilly, Philip D. McCaffrey, and David W. H. Rankin. Experimental equilibrium structures: Application of molecular dynamics simula- tions to vibrational corrections for gas electron diffraction. The Journal of Physical Chemistry A, 113(34):9511–9520, 2009.

[2] L. O. Brockway. Electron diffraction by gas molecules. Reviews of Modern Physics, 8(3):231–266, 1936.

Comment: Thank you very much @LucJ.Burhis. Ref 2 is very valuable as well to me (as I wasn't (any more?) aware of it). Could one summarise, that measuring the diffraction pattern of an object means measuring means in reciprocal space. FT of the reciprocal space data inverts these means of reciprocal parameters.  Then the obvious question is if we are measuring by fitting data to equations formally describing scattering signals (operating in reciprocal space) but containing real space parameters, does this 1/<1/r> idea still hold?

Comment: Your first idea has a formal mathematical treatment: we can consider that the measured electron density is the "true" electron density *convoluted with* a smearing function due to the vibrations and the snapshot effect. Then the measured 3D Fourier transform is the product of the "true" Fourier transform *times* a smearing factor (the Fourier transform of the one smearing the electron density).

Comment: Your last question is interesting. But I would need to think about it on a specific example: I am not very good at broad intuitions!